# A word for "the act of driving something into a success"

Tags: phrase-requests

Suppose that a major achievement for a company has been done thanks to me. Now then, let's have me saying this:

> The last project was a success. Now there is a new project, and I am
>   eager to [make it a success] as well.

I am looking for a word or phrase that denotes "the act of driving something into a success".

Comment: I would consider "carry on the success".

Answer (score 1):

The best word I can think of is ***successful***. In my opinion, it is the most suitable for the sentence you have given.

> I am eager to make it ***successful*** as well.

When we talk about something being a success, we can refer to it as being successful.

Answer (score 0):

To [succeed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/SUCCEed): (from TFD)

> - (intr) to accomplish an aim, esp in the manner desired: he succeeded in winning.

- ... and I am eager to succeed in it as well.

Comment: To me, "I succeeded" feels like the accomplishment of a singular person, whereas "the act of driving something into a success" comes off as being the driving force/responsible person behind a group of people. Saying "we succeeded" might  downplay OP's importance in the whole venture.

Comment: Yes, but according to the question , I think OP wants to stress of his/her ability to make another project successful.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo may use **achieve**

```
Achieve: To succeed in reaching a particular goal, status or standard
```

Source: Oxford Collocations Dictionary

Achieve as intransitive verb: accomplish something successfully; perform at a standard or above standard level:

```
Skills needed to achieve in school
```

Please [Also check](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/achieve)